# help to reiterate through my jquery snippet

Tags: jquery

Code in question:

```
$("#alpha").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#show").slideToggle();
});
```

I have a list of files and its being outputted with PHP in alphabetical. I use this method in PHP:

```
foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {
    if (array_key_exists ("$i", $alpha)) {
        echo '<div id="alpha"><a href="#" name="'.$i.'"><h2>'.$i.'</h2></a></div><div id="show">';
        foreach ($$i as $key=>$value)
            echo '<p>'.$value.' '.$key.'</p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks on the #alpha to toggle the div #show that has the names that belong to a letter up. I can do this with the first listing, but every listing after that isn't affected.

how can i tell jquery that foreach letter apply the js code so it can toggle up/down the #show.

I don't want to this 26 times (one time for each letter in the alphabet), I tried to use class instead of id but that causes all the #show to toggleup heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID attributes [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html). Use class attributes instead of IDs within your generated markup, and target the `.show` which is relative to the clicked `.alpha`:

```
$(".alpha").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".show").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` attribute should be unique per document. Try using `class` instead.

```
echo '<div class="alpha">...';
```

don't forget to update your javascript accordingly

```
$('.alpha').click(...
```

---

And if I may rewrite your PHP

```
foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {
    if (array_key_exists ($i, $alpha)) { // don't need quotes around $i
        echo '<div class="alpha"><a href="#" name="'.$i.'"><h2>'.$i.'</h2></a></div><div id="show">';
        foreach ($$i as $key=>$value) {
            echo "<p>$value $key</p>"; // looks cleaner with double quotes
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Yeah, and `h2` element is not allowed inside `<a>`